# Allow redeploy for "latest" docker tag in Nexus OSS

Tags: docker, nexus

I'm using nexus to host both maven and docker artifacts. For the docker production artifacts I'd like to turn on "disable redeploy" to ensure the image can never change on the nexus server once it is potentially in production.

However, enabling "disable redeploy" appears to make it impossible to re-publish the "latest" tag to point to the latest version.

When trying to push I get obscure errors on the client such as `blob upload invalid: blob upload invalid`.

Is it possible to disable redeploy to concrete version tags, while allowing on tags like "latest"

Comment: In sonartype version 3.21.1 this feature has been added.https://stackoverflow.com/a/60324994/5227589

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In sonartype version 3.21.1 this feature has been added. When the Disable redeploy policy is selected , we get new option: Allow redeploying the 'latest' tag but defer to the Deployment Policy for all other tags.

[image: sonartype]

Link: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-18186

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible. It does seem like a bit of an oddity given how the Docker format works. You can pop over to https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS and file an issue about this functionality.

Comment: a ticket has been created since then: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-18186