# Nexus Repository Manager 3 OSS - Allow re-deploy of Docker Images that fulfills a specific criteria

Tags: docker, repository, bundle, nexus

The Nexus 3 Docker Repo solution requires that re-deploy is allowed in order for the usage of latest tag to work (as described here [Allow redeploy for "latest" docker tag in Nexus OSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907903/allow-redeploy-for-latest-docker-tag-in-nexus-oss))

Since we want our uploaded images to be immutable, but at the same time allow the usage of tagging with latest it puts us into a dilemma.

Current best thinking is to have a white-list of tags that can be re-deployed 
(tags like latest, production etc)

This means that we must be able to trap any Docker Image upload request prior to that the storage request is processed. In the pre-check we must then block the re-deploy if the image is already present in the repo and that the given image tag is NOT within the white-list..

We already have a custom bundle, so we were hoping that we could extend the functionality with this new blocking feature.

Is it possible to something like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow redeploy for "latest" docker tag in Nexus OSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907903/allow-redeploy-for-latest-docker-tag-in-nexus-oss)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60324994/5227589